# cutting special chars in folder name when using GET

Tags: php, ajax, get

I've been visiting stackoverflow.com for a long time and always found the solution to my problem. But this time it's different. That's why I'm posting my first question here.

The situation looks like this: My website provides a directory explorer which allows users to download whole directory as a zip file. The problem is I end up with error when I want to download a dir containg special characters in it's name, i.e. 'c++'. I don't want to force users to NOT name their folders with those special chars, so I need a clue on this one. I noticed that the whole problem comes down to GET protocol. I use ajax POST for example to roll out the directory content, but for making a .zip file and downloading it I need GET:

```
var dir_clicked = $(e.target).attr('path'); //let's say it equals '/c++'
window.location = 'myDownloadSite.php?directory_path='+dir_clicked;
```

I studied whole track of dir_clicked variable, step by step, and it seems that the variable in adress is sent correctly (I see the correct url in browser) but typing:

```
echo $_GET['directory_path']
```

in myDownloadSite.php prints

```
'/c'
```

instead of

```
'/c++'
```

Why the GET protocol is cutting my pluses?

Comment: because `+` in a url is treated as a space character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
encodeURIComponent() //to get the url then use
decodeURIComponent()  //to decode and access ur filename.
```

Use `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` on server side.

Comment: Encoding function works great but I tested it without decoding on server side and also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `encodeURIComponent()` and then remove all %xx occurrences?

Comment: Sorry, typo! http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp is what you're looking for (answer updated)

Comment: it was a syntax - it's actually **encode**URIComponent() and it works just fine! I had to put it only within last part of my url (just the variable), because the function encodes also slash characters

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your URI with `encodeURI(url)` JavaScript function.

```
window.location = encodeURI('myDownloadSite.php?directory_path=' + dir_clicked);
```

Comment: Your suggestion was almost good, because it encodes all chars except '+' and a few others ;)

Comment: You're right! I believe the problem is that when PHP processes the "+" signal it will convert it to a space. Use `encodeURIComponent()` instead and it may work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When the information is posted it is encoded with special chars, sounds like you just need to decode them before using the information.

You can use php function urldecode() to decode the folder names before using them...

```
$_GET[directory_path]=urldecode($_GET[directory_path]);
```